# Align baseline of text to the top of another element (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm sure someone's done this before, but I can't come up with a good enough search query to find anything about it.

I'd like to align the baseline (not the bottom of the text element, the baseline of the text itself) to the top of another div. This also means I'd like the descenders to intersect with the other div below it.

HTML looks something like this:

```
<div id="text">text</div>
<div id="box"></div>
```

So I want `.text` to have its baseline directly on top of the top edge of `.box`, and I want the descenders (like "g") to intersect into `.box`. I was trying to use the `vertical-align` property in CSS but it wasn't working. I have a feeling that's what I need though. Any ideas? Thanks!

[See this image, the gray box would be `.box` and the text part is `.text`.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lf5RM.png) Notice the descenders going down into the box and the baseline having full contact with the box.

Comment: You want something like. https://jsfiddle.net/5ah4kc9c/ ?

Comment: Is there a non-absolute way to do it? I feel like there's a better way to do it that doesn't rely on nudging things down pixel by pixel until it looks right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this, using `line-height`?

```css
#box{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background-color:#ccc;
}
#text{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:48px;
  line-height:30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="text">TEXT<em>pgjiq</em></div>
<div id="box"></div>
```

The difficulty is that the height of the font isn't determined by, say, the height of the capital letter `T` -- it also includes the ascenders and descenders.

There's no way to make CSS cognizant of the amount of space taken up by the ascenders and descenders. Nudging it pixel-by-pixel is your best bet.

If you're worried about this being preserved on different screens and on zooming in and out, it should be fine: browsers are very good at preserving the proportions among dimensions.

That said, the only way to be 100% certain is to use an image or an SVG.

Comment: I was hoping for something that would be a little more fool proof (and hopefully work with something like FitText.js) but I guess this works. I might just use an SVG as you suggested. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        * {font-family: tahoma; font-size: 14px;}
        #text {margin-bottom: -3px;}
        #box {background-color: #ddd; width: 100%; height: 100px;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="text">TEXT gjipq</div>
<div id="box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I was able to accomplish what your image is displaying is by using a negative margin on the bottom box.

```
*{
  margin: 0;
}

.text{
  background: lightgrey;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.box{
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: -12px;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Froy/pen/ZQezjZ?editors=110)